# The program is not collecting data from csv file?

Tags: c++, csv, c++11, push-back

```
#include"std_lib_facilities.h"

void login(){
  fstream fin;
  fin.open("user.csv",ios::in);

  vector<string>data;
  string word;
  string temp;
  string line;
  while(fin>>temp){
    data.clear();
    getline(fin,line);
    stringstream s(line);
    while(getline(s,word,',')){
      data.push_back(word);
    }
  }
  cout<<data.size()<<'\n';
  cout<<data[0]<<'\n';
}

int main()
{
  login();
}
```

I am trying to collect data from the user.csv file and the code i have written is a modified version of a working code written by another programmer(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/csv-file-management-using-c/) but even after trying a lot i am still confused why my code is showing a range error and when i checked the size of vector it is showing 0.....why?? andjust for info the user.csv file contains :

```
hello,testing,qwerty
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the file open failed, so you don't read anything into your vector. Always check that files open!

Comment: `fin>>temp` reads the whole line of text. There's nothing else in the file, so all subsequent reads fail, and you don't put anything into the vector. You don't use the text you read into `temp` either.

Comment: but igor the website showed me the same to do....check the website please

Comment: yes i just modified....

Comment: look at the read csv  code mentioned in the website...i kind of just modifies it..

Comment: Their code is wrong, too. It skips odd-numbered lines and only reads even-numbered ones. So does your code, but your input file only contains one line, so it's more noticeable.

Comment: @SreeHari Code on the web site looks wrong to me for the reasons that Igor mentioned.

Comment: Not to mention clearing the vector inside the loop.

Comment: ok....do you have any alternative....i mean i am a new to parsing csv....

Comment: Bad idea to take code from random websites and this is why

Answer (score -1):

Here's a version of your code that might work

```
void login(){
  ifstream fin("user.csv");
  if (!fin.is_open()) {
      cerr << "file open failed\n";
      return;
  }
  vector<string>data;
  string line;
  while(getline(fin,line)) {
    istringstream s(line);
    string word;
    while(getline(s,word,',')){
      data.push_back(word);
    }
  }
  cout<<data.size()<<'\n';
  cout<<data[0]<<'\n';
}
```

I haven't tested this.

Comment: word not declared in the scope

Comment: @SreeHari Not possible

Comment: its working he just have to declare word as string above....thanks...john...